# Need help on email creative

Tags: html-table, html-email

I'm trying to make email creative.

I give each td the width of 156px - but for some reason they are in size of 228px.

You can see what I did here:

http://lirantadmor.co.il/emailhelp

So why each td is 228px when I give them 156px?

Answer (score 0):

All TDs must add up to the total specified in `<table>`. You currently have this set to 700 pixels.

Beware: not all CSS properties are supported in HTML Emails. Here is a handy reference:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table that is set to be a width of 720px, then your row will need to be 720px. The sum of all your td's doesn't equal to the width you set on the table so it will expand to fit the width of the table/row

Comment: ok,so now the boxes are setup right, you can see that I updated  lirantadmor.co.il/emailhelp

my question now is what is the best way to add three more boxes like those under the three ones that are already there.

basically,i'm trying to get to thise result:

lirantadmor.co.il/result.jpg

thanks again

Comment: That tall nested table you have will push the height of the row to be extremely tall. You will need to set this td to rowspan="3". This will make it span across 3 different rows, you can then add the next 2 rows  and they should display below your other row and to the right of the nested table. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: this is what I made

http://trailer.web-view.net/Show/0XCDA5FB5CA7863C9E08AE00CBC1ED00BF5180F651BAF7FD4159C099BC03D3AE98.htm

how can I get rid of lines that I have in the corners? 

thanks.

Comment: Set valign="top" on the rows where you want your corner images to show

Comment: ok,so now this is what I'm getting:http://trailer.web-view.net/Show/0XCDA5FB5CA7863C9E380958A63677436DE46DCAC6CEFB5D8459C099BC03D3AE98.htm , so what should I do about the buttoms lines? I tried to give valign="buttom" to them but that didn't help.thanks again for your help,it's werry appreciated

Comment: valign="bottom" should work... shows fine in my browser. Alternatively to do this without the aligning you could make your images have a height of 19 as that is the actual height of the row so should show fine without any valigns. Though like I said, the valign="bottom" SHOULD work. Are you testing this in your browser or just an email client? Just be sure to test it in your browser to make sure you're doing it correct, if it doesnt work in the email client then it's obviously not supported so you may need to try the resized image route.

Comment: im my browser it's look fine,but in gmail for some reason I still see the line(only in the bottom),that is weird becasue the "top" is ok...when I tried to give the picture the height of 19 it just make it bigger,but the line on the buttom continue to be there. any chance I can see you the email from my email client so maybe will you know what is the issue? :) if so please email me at lirantadmor@gmail.com and I'll send you the creative email from my email client,thanks so much.